# Elasticsearch 1.7 scripted_metric analyzed string

Tags: python, elasticsearch, groovy

I have a scripted metric and I'm trying to get the value of an analyzed string, which is returning an array of strings.

I'm trying to get the correct value for an analyzed field which is returning the string sorted alphabetically and split by spaces. Is working well well with not analyzed string.

Scripted metric with an analyzed field:

```py
"aggs": {
            'influencers': {
                'scripted_metric': {
                    "init_script": "_agg['transactions'] = []",
                    'map_script': """
                        result = [:];
                        result['field_analyzed1'] = doc['field_analyzed1'].values;
                        result['field_analyzed2'] = doc['field_analyzed2'].value;
                        result['field_not_analyzed'] = doc['field_not_analyzed'].value;
                        _agg.transactions.add(result);
                        """
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to get the following string `Francisco Claudio Urbano` but the result of `field_analyzed1` is `['claudio', 'francisco', 'urbano']` and the result of `field_analyzed2` is `claudio`, only the first string of the array. With the field `field_not_analyzed` the result is correct `Francisco Claudio Urbano`.

I think with newer versions I can do something like this or use painless scripting:

```
result['field_text'] = doc['field_text.keyword'].value;
```

But I need it with the ES 1.7

```
body = {
    'script_fields': {
        'test': {
            'script': 'doc["analyzed_field"].value',
            'lang': 'groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In 1.7 you can create a sub field "fields" : {
          "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        } similar to keyword field in new versions

Comment: Also is similiar to create a new field, but in this case we duplicate the text, we write the text in the not analyzed field and in the analyzed field. In the future versions of Elasticsearch we write in one field and we use keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1.7 you can create a non analyzed sub field

```
"properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "fields" : {
                    "raw": {
                        "type" : "string",
                         "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is similar to type keyword in new versions